Convergence of: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\sin (n \theta)}{n}$, $ \theta \in [-\pi, \pi] $
I'm currently studying the convergence properties of the series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\sin (n \theta)}{n}
$$
where the constraint that $\theta$ is in the interval $[- \pi, \pi]$.
I'm aware that this series arises from the Fourier series of the sawtooth function, and I'm not particularly concerned about uniform convergence but rather pointwise convergence. Since I couldn't find a proof of this nature on the forum, I decided to derive one from scratch. I would appreciate any feedback on my attempt.
Attempt at Proof:
We'll employ Dirichlet's Test, which is applicable when dealing with series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n$ where:

$a_n$ is a sequence of real numbers decreasing monotonically to 0 as $n$ approaches infinity.
The partial sums $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n$ are bounded for all $N$.

Let's denote $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n = (-1)^{n+1} \sin(n \theta)$. Then, we'll verify the conditions of Dirichlet's Test:

The sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is positive and decreasing monotonically to 0 as $n$ approaches infinity, satisfying the first condition.

For the second condition, we need to show that the partial sums $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} (-1)^{n+1} \sin(n \theta)$ are bounded for all $N$.


The second point is challenging, as it requires some insight to establish. Could someone assist me in understanding how to prove it? Thank you in advance.

For information: since you know that this is the Fourier series of the sawtooth function (which is a function of bounded variation), the Dirichlet--Jordan test applies and even tells you the exact value of this series for every $\theta$.



For the second condition, we need to show that the partial sums $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} (-1)^{n+1} \sin(n \theta)$ are bounded for all
$N$.

The second point is challenging, as it requires some insight to
establish. Could someone assist me in understanding how to prove it?
Thank you in advance.

Yes. If $\theta = n\pi/2$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N},$ then the result is easy to prove.
If $\theta\neq n\pi/2$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N},$ then $\theta/2 \neq n\pi/2,\implies \sin(\theta/2)\neq 0$ and $\cos(\theta/2)\neq 0$  and using this result and a similar one for $\cos,$ we see that each of the sequences $a_N(\theta):= \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sin(n\theta)$ and $b_N(\theta):= \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos(n\theta)$ are bounded.
Suppose $N$ is even. Then,
$$S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} (-1)^{n+1} \sin(n \theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \sin((2n-1) \theta) - \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \sin(2n \theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \sin(2n\theta-\theta)- \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \sin(2n \theta) $$
$$ = \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \left(\sin(2n\theta)\cos\theta-\cos(2n\theta)\sin\theta\right) - \sum_{n=1}^{N/2}\sin(2n\theta)) $$
$$ = (\cos\theta - 1) \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \sin(n(2\theta)) - \sin\theta \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \cos(n(2\theta)) $$
$$ = (\cos\theta - 1)a_{N/2}(2\theta) - b_{N/2}(2\theta), $$
Since $\theta\neq n\pi/2,\ 2\theta\neq n\pi,\ $ and so both $a_{N/2}(2\theta)$ and $- b_{N/2}(2\theta)$ are bounded sequences.
The analysis is similar if $N$ is odd.
Therefore $S_N$ is a bounded sequence.

Given a real $\theta$, we want to show the series
$$ S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1} \sin(n\theta) $$ is bounded.
First, since $\sin(x+n\pi) = (-1)^n \sin x$,
$$ S_N = - \sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n\theta + n\pi) = -\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n\zeta) $$
where $\zeta = \theta+\pi \in \mathbb{R}$. TO make use of de Moivre's formula, let's define
$$ \begin{align*} a_N &= \sum_{n=1}^N \cos(n\zeta) \\
 z_N &= a_N - i S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \big(\!\cos(n\zeta) + i \sin(n\zeta)\big) \end{align*}$$
If $\zeta$ is an exact multiple of $2\pi$, then $S_N$ is identically zero, so bounded. Otherwise,
$$ z_N = \sum_{n=1}^N e^{in\zeta} = \frac{1-e^{i(N+1)\zeta}}{1-e^{i\zeta}} $$
$$ |S_N| \leq |z_N| \leq \frac{2}{|1-e^{i\zeta}|} = \frac{1}{\sin \frac\zeta 2} $$
So the real sequence $S_N$ at each $\theta$ is bounded. But the sequence of functions $S_N$ in terms of $\theta$ is not uniformly bounded.

Since $e^{ix} = \cos{x} + i\sin{x}$, your sum becomes the imaginary part of a geometric sum
\begin{align*}
S_N &= \Im{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n+1}e^{in\theta}\right)} = \Im{\left(-\frac{(-e^{i\theta})\left((-e^{i\theta})^N-1\right)}{-e^{i\theta}-1}\right)} = \Im{\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}(1-(-1)^Ne^{iN\theta})}{e^{i\theta}+1}\right)} \\
&=\Im{\left(\frac{e^{i\theta/2}(1-(-1)^Ne^{iN\theta})}{e^{i\theta/2}+e^{-i\theta/2}}\right)} = \frac{1}{2\cos{(\theta/2)}}\Im{\left(\left(\cos{(\theta/2)}+i\sin{(\theta/2)}\right)(1-(-1)^N\cos{N\theta}-i(-1)^N\sin{N\theta})\right)} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{N+1}\cos{(\theta/2)}\sin{N\theta}+\sin{(\theta/2)}-(-1)^N\sin{(\theta/2)\cos{N\theta}}}{2\cos{(\theta/2)}}
\end{align*}
which is bounded for every $N$, but notice that in order to do this computations we need that $-e^{i\theta} \neq 1$, i.e. $\theta \neq \pm \pi$, but this cases are trivial.

Our answers are similar. Just an observation
